# Change background of navigation bar, only for home page

Tags: reactjs

I need that when the user returns to the home the color of the navigation bar becomes transparent so that the background of the view is appreciated in full screen

I found an example page with the desired effect: https://angular.io/ I need to do this but in react

[here my project code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN55X.png)

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the specifics of your app. Do you have any (relevant) code to share? Have you tried anything yourself (show us in that case)? What kind of routing are you using, if any?

Comment: Yes, hello, thank you for responding. do not add that two days ago install react for the first time to migrate from jquery, and I'm copying and pasting everything I find on the internet. I'm just doing tests. There I upload an image with code.

Comment: Okay, looks like you are using react router. Is it version 4?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0"
  },

Comment: Alright. Can you check if you have access to `this.props.location` in any of your routes?

Comment: I'm trying but I do not understand anything. When I have news, I write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. In Header.js render method you can check `window.location.pathname` if it matches `/` which is root and usually homepage. If that is correct, append some class to header element and style it accordingly.
2. In Header.js you can `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";` after which you can use HOC (Higher Order Component) withRouter in the bottom where you export the component `export default withRouter(Header);`

After this you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method (read more [here](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/)), and check if `nextProps.location.pathname` matches `/` and set state accordingly, which then you can use to append class.

**Note**
Recent activity on this answer prompted me to update this as most of this is obsolete. Recommended use now is to use `useLocation` hook instead of withRouter HOC or window.location.pathname, but the latter will still work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header class / style based on the route params from `react-router`.
Then if you're in the homepage route set the color and maybe make it not fixed (if you want it to behave like in angular.io)

Comment: can u give me an example please? or a page reference., im in 0

Answer (score 0):

I garet, thanks. this is my code

index.js

```
.
.
 import {... HashRouter,withRouter**} from 'react-router-dom';
.
.
 const HeaderWithRouter = withRouter(Header);//<- needed this
ReactDOM.render(
    <div className="App"> 

         <HashRouter>
             <HeaderWithRouter/> // to use here to have access to this.props.location in the header
        </HashRouter>

        <div className="app-body">
          <main className="main">
            <Container fluid>
                <HashRouter>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" name="Home" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/login" name="Login" component={Login}/>
                    <Redirect from="/" to="/home"/>
                  </Switch>
                </HashRouter>
.
.
.
```

header.js

```
<Navbar className={(this.props.location.pathname === "/home") ?"headerTransparent":"navbar-inverse"} collapseOnSelect >
```